# Samsung S3 lost all free applications

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

This morning, I turned on my phone and it seems to have lost every free app (including Google Play Store, Google Search and Gmail). However:

- Every paid-for app is still installed and working.
- My contacts, photos and other data seem to be intact.
- The missing applications are still listed in the application manager, but are lacking their icons and names (e.g. Spotify displays as com.spotify.mobile.android.ui) and display with size 0.00B.

Any ideas on what might have happened? It's currently running Android 4.3, but I'm not sure when it might have last updated.

Comment: Are you sure they are really gone? Maybe something got "messed up" a little, and a restart fixes that? Though it sounds strange the paid-for apps are the only ones not affected.

Comment: I've tried restarting (both restart, shutdown and turn on and removing the battery). Nothing seems to fix it.

Is it worth leaving it turned off for a while and starting it again?

Comment: IMHO that should make no difference here (though trying doesn't hurt). I'm totally at a miss what that could be. Rawly guessing, have all those apps be placed on SD (App2SD or the like)? And maybe the SDCard doesn't mount anymore (or too late, or has errors)?

Comment: So no, the other thing is that all their cached data is still included when I examine the missing applications' listings in the app manager. For example, iPlayer has a good 320MB of cached material saved, and knows that it belongs to the bbc.iplayer.android ap.

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas so far. Maybe you [edit] your question and include the additional facts from the comments (e.g. concerning (no) App2SD, and your cache investigation) to make them easier to spot?